# How do I read the last line to the first file in PHP?

Tags: php, text

I have it where it prints the file to the body but I need to do that but have the file's data load from the last line to the first.

**The code I have right now**

```
$file = fopen('text.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
echo($line);
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `file()` to read the file into an array of lines. Then you can reverse the array and loop through it.

```
$lines = file('text.txt');
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```